# Writing a method that accepts an integer parameter n and returns as a the sum of the first n terms of the sequence

Tags: java

∑i=1n1i

In other words, the method should generate the following sequence:

```
1+12+13+14+15+⋯
```

I've been stumped on this problem for quite a bit. Having a tough time understand what "n" stands for in the equation and applying it to my for loop.

Would a for loop be optimal for solving this? Or should I just use a formula and somehow solve it then?

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
//Chapter 4 Exercise 1
        System.out.println("--Chapter 4, Exercise 1");
        System.out.println("How many integers do you want?:");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numb = console.nextInt();
        fractionSum(numb)


 public static double fractionSum(int numb) {
      for(int i = 1; i <numb; i++) {
           if (i !=1)
               System.out.print("1 + 1" + i);
           else
               System.out.print("1");
        }
        return(numb);
    }

1+12+13+14+15+⋯
```

Should be the output.

My output is coming out as:

```
11 + 121 + 131 + 141 + 15
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answering the first part of your question:**

∑i=1n1i is known as the **Harmonic Sum** - the output you give in your question is wrong, harmonic sum can be described as the sum of reciprocals of the positive integers - for example:

```
H1 = 1
H2 = 1 + 1/2 = 1.5
H3 = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 = 1.8333
H4 = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 = 2.0833
H(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... + 1/n = answer ---> see what n is now?
```

You should use a for-loop for this, and its not very complex. Hopefully, this answer will clear up the task for you (I assume homework from Chapter 4 Exercise 1) and you can try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
class Harmonic {
    public static void main(String… s) {
        int n, i;
        float sum = 0;

        n = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum = sum + (float) 1 / i;
        }

        System.out.println(“nSum = ”+sum);
    }
}
```